# URL Rewriting/Regex Debug

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need a set of fresh eyes on this. I'm having a tough time spotting the problem.

In folder X I have an .htaccess file with the following two lines in it:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\.-]+)/?$ item-display.php?bibid=$1 [NC,L]
```

My interpretation is that anything in that directory will then be redirected to the item-display page. The problem is that on the item-display page, echoing out the value of bibid outputs 'display-item'. So somehow I'm redirecting from:
http://localhost/test/cat/item/14056a
to: http://localhost/test/cat/item/item-display.php?bibid=item-display

Any ideas?

Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to exclude the file you are redirecting to as that is also matched by the pattern:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/item-display\.php$
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\.-]+)/?$ item-display.php?bibid=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Actually this is safer than mine I think :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewritePath /test/cat/item
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\.-]+)/?$ item-display.php?bibid=$1 [L]
```

I think the problem is that it is looking at the whole URL and not just the last item ID part.

Comment: I think you're after RewriteBase...it doesn't appear to change the results though. Gets to the right page, then thinks bibid is set to 'display-item'. I'm reading into RewriteBase further hoping to find something in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

The request is sub-processed so it extracts the rewritten URL's filename part I presume. Try adding the NS flag.